# Question about jquery slideDown

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, slidedown

I have a div with hight 300px
I want to use slideDown or any of jquery methods to slide down a part of the div not all the 300px 
may be just 50px

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uMP8X/1/)

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
  $('#book').animate({
      top: '+=50',
      height: '-=50'
  }, 1000, function() {
      // callback on complete.
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#your_div").scrollTop(50)
```

isn't it right?